# DHIS2 Import Data

Tags: csv, import, dhis-2

Im using DHIS 2 Live with embedded database.
I have and excel, with some data, i transformed it to csv and tried to import it using the import tools.

[ImportTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9tvd.png)

[ImportExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbL5r.png)

It doesnt print any error just stop and does not insert anything.
I tried to import some data in json too but i dont know if i should import it like data or meta data.

Comment: have you seen [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/108001/821070)